# Cloning a textarea so TinyMCE reconnects to the clone

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I have a syllabus form that can have 1 to n sections the user can input.  I have JS that on click clones the previous fieldset and it's contents, increments the ids, appends the fieldset to the form, then appends the add button to the end of the form, and shifts the submit button to the end.  Unfortunately when the textarea that is connected to TinyMCE clones it does not become editable even though it has a different id from the textarea it is cloned from.

https://jsfiddle.net/etmftLoe/

```
$("button[name='add']").on("click",function(){
    var fieldset = $(this).parents("fieldset");

    //remove tinymce
    fieldset.find("textarea").each(function(){
        tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor',true, this.id);
    });
    var form = $(this).parents("form");
    var n = fieldset.parent().children("fieldset").length;

    $(this).detach();
    var clone = fieldset.clone(true,true);
    clone.find("input").each(function() {
        this.id = this.id.replace(/\d+$/, "") + n;
        this.value = "";
    });
    clone.find("label").each(function() {
        this.setAttribute("for", this.getAttribute("for").replace(/\d+$/, "") +n);  
    });
    clone.find("textarea").each(function() {
        this.id = this.id.replace(/\d+$/, "") + n;
        this.value = "";
        //add tinymce to clone
        tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceAddEditor',true, this.id);
    });
    //add tinymce to original
    fieldset.find("textarea").each(function(){
        tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceAddEditor',true, this.id);
    });
    clone.appendTo(form);
    $(this).appendTo(clone);
    form.find(':submit').appendTo(form);
});
```

I think I need to remove the control from the source fieldset, clone it, then add it back to both the source and the clone. But my attempts to add and remove with `tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand` are not effective.  The Original textarea is still editable but the new one isn't. Am I missing a trick?

Comment: tinymce 4.x uses `mceAddEditor` rather than 3.x `mceAddControl`... could that be the issue?

Comment: nope, still not working.  It is adding the editor to the clone.  but not making it editable.

Comment: Looks like you're setting both the `input` and `textarea` elements to the same `id`? (Rather than using your `var n = fieldset...` code to create the new id, consider using instead `tinymce.DOM.uniqueId()`.)

Comment: I am replacing the index at the end of the id with the same index.  But the first input id is `section_name_0` and the first textarea id is `section_details_0`.  So on cloning I have `section_name_1` and `section_details_1`.  I need to to that so the `for=` will point to the right place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use the `tinymce.EditorManager` commands at all
after cloning the textarea. I delete the tinyMce div and "unhide" the textarea:

```
$(this).parent().find('div.mce-tinymce').remove();
$(this).show();
```

and then execute the classic JavaScript command to add tinyMce to my textarea **after a short timeout**:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  tinymce.init({
    selector: <your selector>,
    ...
  });
}, 50);
```